# Scrolling header and footer in form

Tags: ms-access-2010

I have an application, in which the user tracks product orders.

I want to show all products ordered in a form, which is a bill.

So I set `Default View` property to `Continuous Forms` and I filtered the result when I opened the form with `DoCmd.OpenForm`

The rows have a scroll bar to navigate, but I want to navigate not only the rows, but the header and footer too.

The header and footer should not show the whole time, they should also scroll with the rows.

Comment: Not clear at all what the question is!

Comment: Thanks for your comment, it permmits me to improve my question. I updated my question. I hope it's better now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot include header and footer in the scrolling when using an Access Form.

If you do not need to update the values, perhaps you should rather use an Access Report. Then you can scroll the header and footer too.

Comment: As it is a bill, no I don't need to update it. That's exactly what I need, thanks a lot !